# Some confusions about Androids App-Widgets

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm currently playing around with App Widgets in Android and I'm a little confused about the `appWidgetsIds`-parameter in the `AppWidgetProvider`s `onUpdate`-method.

[The Docs say](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onUpdate%28android.content.Context,%20android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager,%20int%5B%5D%29):

> **appWidgetIds**: The appWidgetIds for which an update is needed. Note that
>   this may be all of the AppWidget
>   instances *for this provider*, or just a
>   subset of them.

So I suggested that if I have two instances of my Widget on the Home-Screen, there would be two ID's in the Array. So I added two instances of it but the array contains eight elements.

There are no other Widgets on the Home-Screen.

Am I missing something here or is this a Android Bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after clearing all the Apps Data and completely reinstalling it, it now works.

So, I'm not sure what the problem was, I only know it's solved now.

Comment: you can accept your own question :) (you won't get any points though!)

Comment: Yes, but only after tow days ;)

Comment: You may have overrode the method that tell's the system when an app widget has been removed without calling its super(), therefore it had every instance of the widgets you had added and deleted in the ID array. So yea a full reinstall wud fix that

Comment: @Blundell After the reinstall I didn't change anything on the code and when i delete an instance now, it's not in the array. But I had this thought, too.

Comment: @Lukas I've seen it where if you change things about the widgets service in your manifest file, this can affect it. Just a vague memory sorry I don't have anything concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Up to and including Android 1.6 widgets which fail to get added to the home screen are still in the list. I call them "phantom widgets". They get created when you try to add a widget but there's not enough space and you will get a message about that. But the widget somehow still makes it to the internal list. I think this was supposed to be fixed with 2.0 but I'm not sure.